# How to pass a created object to another class Java

Tags: java

I have created an instance of an object in one of my classes for a Java program. How can I pass the same instance of that object to another class?

Would I need to do something like creating some type of a getter method in the original class to pass the object through to the other class?

Comment: You said getter, but I would suggest you use a setter (or pass it in the constructor).

Comment: Note that the answer to your question also depends on the number of threads in your model.  If your program is single-threaded, the answers you have received are all apt.  If you wish to pass an object to another thread, however, you have to consider synchronization for data consistency as well.  In general, objects that you wish to send to other threads must be "safely published" to assure that the receiving thread does not receive stale or inconsistent data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "pass" it you need a method or a constructor in the other class that can accept it:

```
public class Other {
    // either
    public Other(MyClass obj) {
        // do something with obj
    }
    // or
    public void method(MyClass obj) {
        // do something with obj
    }
}
```

Then call the constructor/method:

```
MyClass x = new MyClass();

Other other = new Other();
other.method(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to pass the reference for one object to another object.  The simplest and most common ways are:

- as a constructor parameter,
- as a parameter of a setter method; e.g. `setFoo(Foo foo)` to set the "foo" attribute, or
- as an "add" method in the object being passed is going to be added to a collection; e.g. `addFoo(Foo foo)`.

Then there are a variety of more complicated patterns where objects are passed using publish/subscribe, call-backs, futures, and so on.

Finally there are some tricks that can be used to "smuggle" objects across abstraction boundaries ... which are generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the object via the constructor of the other class.

Simple Example:

```
Class A{
}

Class B{
    A a;
    public B(A obj){
      this.a=obj
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you want to pass an object of class `A` to class `B`. Now you have created the object like this:

```
A object = new A ();
```

And now in your `B` class, you can write a method to accept a `A` object. It should be `public` and you can make it `static` if you like.

If you want to pass `object` to `B`, you must want to do something with it, right? So you should name your method accordingly. You probably want to assign a field of type `A` (Let's call this `fieldA`) in `B`. (or maybe that isn't what you want, but I'll use this for the example)

Let's look at the method:

```
public void setFieldA (A a) {
    fieldA = a;
}
```

You can call this method as follows:

```
anObjectOfClassB.setFieldA (object);
```

Of course you don't need `anObjectOfClassB` if it is static.